# How to normalize data and clear array

Tags: c, arrays, normalization, func

Hi i've written a small program that let's me choose from a menu what i want to do ie view, enter values, compute etc. its doing most of the stuff im asking it, so im on the right track. However, there are a few things i dont know how to fix.

1. when i enter values and exit. When i re-enter it starts from 0 again, as if everything cleared. I want to start off where i left off. Secondly. i want to have MAX 10 values as input. I should not be able to keep entering. I want to erase the array using my function instead.
2. im trying to compute normalized values but program quits everytime.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 10

int enterMeasurements();
void printArray();
int minValue();
int maxValue();
float avgValue();
void normValue();

int main(void)
{
   char input;
   int nrMeasurements=0;
   int arrayTable[LENGTH] = {0};
   int normTable[LENGTH] = {0};
   int max, min, norm;
   float avg;
   //main menu
   do
   {

      printf("\nMeasurement tool 1.0\n");
      printf("V for (View)\n");
      printf("E for (Enter Values)\n");
      printf("C for (Compute Values)\n");
      printf("R for (Reset Values)\n");
      printf("Q for (Quit)\n");
      printf("\nEnter input: ");
      scanf(" %c", &input);

      if(input == 'v' || input == 'V')
      {
         // function to print array values
         printArray(arrayTable, nrMeasurements);
      }
      else if(input == 'e' || input == 'E')
      {
         // enter values here
         nrMeasurements = enterMeasurements(arrayTable,nrMeasurements);
      }
      else if (input == 'c' || input == 'C')
      {
         // enter function to calc min, max and avg and prints it.
         max = maxValue(arrayTable, nrMeasurements);
         min = minValue(arrayTable, nrMeasurements);
         avg = avgValue(arrayTable, nrMeasurements);
         printf("Maximum value is: %d\n", max);
         printf("Minimum value is: %d\n", min);
         printf("Average value is: %.2f\n", avg);
         normValue(normTable, nrMeasurements);


      }
      else if (input == 'r' || input == 'R')
      {
         // enter function that erase the entire array.
         printf("[   erase array   ]\n");
      }
   }
   while (input !='q' && input != 'Q');
   return 0;
}

int enterMeasurements(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter Measurement #%i (or 0): ", i+1);
      scanf("%d", &arrayTable[i]);


      if (arrayTable[i] == 0 )
         break;
   }
   return i;
}

void printArray(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < nrMeasurements; i++)
   {
      printf(" array[%2d] : %d\n", i, arrayTable[i]);
   }
}

int maxValue(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements)
{
   int i, max;
   max = arrayTable[0];
   for (i=1; i<nrMeasurements; i++)
   {
      if (arrayTable[i]>max)
      {
         max=arrayTable[i];
      }
   }
   return(max);
}

int minValue(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements)
{
   int i, min;
   min = arrayTable[0];
   for (i=1; i<nrMeasurements; i++)
   {
      if (arrayTable[i]<min)
      {
         min=arrayTable[i];
      }
   }
   return(min);
}

float avgValue(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements)
{
   int sum,i;
   float avg;
   sum=0;
   avg=0;

   for (i=0; i<nrMeasurements;i++)
   {
      sum=sum+arrayTable[i];
      avg=(float)sum/(i+1);
   }
   return(avg);
}

void normValue(int min, int max, int avg, int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements, int normTable[])
{
   int i;

   for (i=0; i<nrMeasurements; i++)
   {
      normTable[i]=(arrayTable[i]-min)/ (max-min);
   }
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
      printf("Normalized Values: %d\n", normTable[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your post in a way that makes answers non-sensical. With your update, the part of my answer that tells to add the declaration at the top does not make sense any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i enter values and exit. When i re-enter it starts from 0 again, as if everything cleared.

That happens since you are always starting from `i = 0;` in `enterMeasurements`. You need to initialize it to the arugment `nrMeasurements`.

> im trying to compute normalized values but program quits everytime.

That's happening most likely because you are not passing enough arguments to `normValue`.

Change the call to:

```
normValue(min, max, avg, arrayTable, nrMeasurements, normTable);
```

You should update the function declarations to contain all the arguments. This would have avoided the above error.

```
int enterMeasurements(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements);
void printArray(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements);
int minValue(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements);
int maxValue(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements);
float avgValue(int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements);
void normValue(int min, int max, int avg, int arrayTable[], int nrMeasurements, int normTable[]);
```

Comment: Hi @R Sahu thanks for helping. `i = nrMeasurements` fixed my issue. Secondly i properly declared everything but now its not compiling. for the line `normValue(normTable, nrMeasurements);` i get a error message saying too few arguments to function call. what does it mean?

Comment: @R Sahu Hi thanks again. Sorry i should not have edited the post. However back to the questions im getting normalized values such as 0, 0, 0, 1. This is from entering 1,2,3,4 in the array.  do i something wrong in my function?

Comment: @Alex, that's most likely the result of integer division. You should change the normalized values to float or double, and make sure to update the line that computes them to use floating point division.

Comment: @R Sahu hmm i've tried that now i can get negative and decimal numbers, but they all turn into the same values like -0.10 even though all entered values are different. Is there a way to get whole number and or negative number?

Comment: @Alex, try to use a debugger. it's difficult for me to see where the problem could be.